# how to get max(likes) in limit 20 from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to do like MySQL query get max likes from MySQL database limit 20.
 means query search database and get 20 ids where likes max.
like this =-> i have 100 post and some post have 50 likes and some have 80 and some have 70 likes then.. i need result back 20 post which have 60 to 80 likes. below my script

```
$myboxexi=mysql_query('select * from boxes where `like_count`=(select max(`like_count`) order by id limit 10)');
```

but its show just 1 result and i need 20 result how can i do this?

Comment: you need 20 but you add a limit of 10 ?

Comment: @Dagon its just for test but i get only 1 result not 10.

Comment: Can you supply some sample data and desired results.  I think there's a communication gap...

Comment: dont have any exaple to show.. but listen i use my above query then i get 1 post i need result back  like get 20posts which have max likes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myboxexi=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM boxes ORDER BY `like_count` DESC LIMIT 20;');
```

Comment: hmm its show result all by like_count post but i need result like show 20 results from maximum likes

Comment: Well, it starts from the max and gets down to lower like values ... ? I don't get it.

Comment: yeh i get it as you say but i need top 20 post which have max likes

Comment: I don't get what you want. `like_count` is "max likes", right? Or is "max likes" a different column?

Comment: You want all (or 20) rows, where `like_count` is between 60 and 80 (or MAX - 20)?

Comment: i just want to get 20 post which have max likes there is no specific value for likes just get max likes i mean if 30 post have 100 above likes then fetch 20 post which have 100++ likes

Comment: In other words you want the top 20, which the SELECT above does.

Comment: yeh i need just top 20 result

Comment: You did not even try the SQL above, right? There is an error ;)

Comment: but this script which u post above its also show post which have 0 likes

Comment: i try and i saw 1 bracket extra and i remove this but dont tell you :- ))

Comment: No, because I don't understand you.

Comment: i dont understand ur last comemnt : o